# Laravel что использовать для высоконагруженного бэкенда

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, postgresql

пишу бэкенд на Laravel, примерно каждую секунду на API будут идти 50 запросов на insert/update/select.
Цель сделать это максимально быстро и просто (mvp)

У меня три связанных вопроса:

- 1.Справится ли с этой задачей mysql "из коробки" ?
- 2.Или без асинхронной бд типо PostgreSQL не обойтись?
- 3.Подойдет ли под это дело Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Если планируется высокая нагрузка, то лучше использовать PostgreSQL + pgbouncer а так-же репликацию. Select оставить на slave, insert/update на master соответственно.

В качестве веб сервера лучше использовать nginx + php-fpm

Так же советую посмотреть в сторону контейнеризации и оркестрации. docker + docker swarm на начальном этапе будет самое то.

А вообще 50 RPS это не так уж и много.

Самым узким местом станет БД с количеством подключений